# getting stocks on hand from two dependent tables and join the result to another table

Tags: mysql, stocks

I have a problem with regards to the stated title. I want to get the stocks_on_hand from these two tables, namely:

```
stocks_added
product_id  quantity_added
ANK001      50

stocks_released
product_id  quantity_released
ANK001      20
```

after getting the stocks_on_hand (result of the two tables), i want to join it to the products table:

```
product_id  product_name  price
ANK0001     ANKLET        200
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @BhupeshC yes but im confused in using join keywords :(

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for editing. :) I seriously didnt know how to do tables here. I just started using SO today.

Comment: I didn't edit that, [Bohemian did](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22509326/2) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use joins and sum():

```
select
    p.product_id, product_name, price,
    coalesce(sum(quantity_added), 0) - coalesce(sum(quantity_released), 0) as stocks_on_hand 
from products p
left join stocks_added a on a.product_id = p.product_id
left join stocks_released r on r.product_id = p.product_id
group by p.product_id, product_name, price
```

Using outer (ie left) joins means you'll get a row for every product whether or not there are rows in the stock movement tables. Using `coalesce()` means a default value of zero is used when there are no rows in the stock table.

Comment: Hi @Bohemian. I have tried the code you suggested and it worked :) but what if, lets say, i have a duplicate ANK001 in the stocks_added table but with a different quantity like 50, how will i add the GROUP BY syntax using the code you gave?

Comment: @jaegyo23 The query will work as is. The query returns the *total* of all `quantity_added` for the product (no matter how many rows there are) minus the *total* of all `quantity_released` for the product (no matter how many rows there are).